# Writing a monitoring system to monitor 300 nodes

Tags: perl, ping

I am thinking of writing my own code (in order to practice and also to serve my company need) to monitor my 300 routers. I want to do the following

1) icmp monitoring. Email when packet loss is above 60%
2) Latency monitoring, email when latency is above 30 ms.

Now quite a time ago, when i asked similar question on cisco forum, they recommended me perl and freebsd. From that time it was in my mind that perl can do it. But i am just confused what approach shall i take. Do i need to do some multi threaded programming here ? as you know i am a little noob here, so if someone can pls guide me a little how to do it. I know there are enterprise class NMS for this but still i thought writing my own would be a good learning experience for me. Also perl is not must but i just thought perl would do it.

EDIT: I am sorry but a dear friend pointed me my mistake. Can someone tell me can i use multithreaded programming in perl ?

Thanks

Comment: Nice topic, but as is the question is not suitable for Stack Overflow. [Please edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8491520/edit) so that it describes a specific problem you need help with (see the [FAQ#dontask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for the reasoning), or else it risks being closed as "not constructive"/"soliciting arguments, polling, extended discussion".

Comment: Oh i am sorry sir, i will do it right away.

Comment: Why not just use something like Nagios?

Comment: Well, here is the std Perl threads tutorial http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html . 
And more MS specific http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/docs/ActivePerl/5.8/lib/threads.html as you'll prob be using ActiveState Perl.

Comment: NEW, you're mistaken, there's nothing MS specific about that. It's just the standard [`threads` module documentation](http://p3rl.org/threads), but outdated by a couple of versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, multi-threaded programming is possible with e.g. [threads](http://p3rl.org/threads), [threads::lite](http://p3rl.org/threads%3a%3alite) and [Coro](http://p3rl.org/Coro).

Threads are not the only means of concurrent programming.

Perl is much stronger with the traditional Unix mechanisms building on the [fork](http://enwp.org/Fork_%28operating_system%29) system call. Nice wrapper modules include [Proc::Fork](http://p3rl.org/Proc%3a%3aFork), [Forks::Super](http://p3rl.org/Forks%3a%3aSuper) and [Parallel::ForkManager](http://p3rl.org/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager).

Another way to solve your problem is employing an event loop, such as [AnyEvent](http://p3rl.org/AE), [Reflex](http://p3rl.org/Reflex) or [POE](http://p3rl.org/POE).

Comment: Sir just 1 thing, do you think my choice of using perl is ok ? dont know why but i was feeling a bit excited in working with it. I have seen alot of threads claiming python to be better then perl, dont want to start a debate here but do you think shall i proceed on with perl ?

Comment: I do not know the exact details of your project apart from what you wrote above. I estimate it is certainly doable in both languages with similar effort and joy. People who claim “one true language” are terrible fanatics and should be ignored. - Note that often times Perl vs. Python has been discussed on SO, search the archives. These questions have been closed quickly because debates do not fit well into the question-and-answer model of this site.